# How to deal with worker thread indefinitely waiting on queue get after all tasks are done?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, python-multithreading

I have a bunch of workers with the following code:

```
while True:
            inp = q.get()
<do stuff>
            q.task_done()
```

The queue is then joined in the main thread, and workers remain waiting.

How can I make the workers gracefully shut down in this situation? The only way I know of would be to push a bunch of Nones into the queue and check for them, but this solution looks extremely hackish. I have to do this before the program terminates, so daemon threads are not an option. Also, merely checking for empty queue is insufficient, since the workers may add tasks dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you workers exit by, as you've guessed, posting a `None` or other sentinel into the input queue.  Here's a tiny example with a single worker:

## simple worker thread exits on None

```
import threading, Queue

def howdy(q):
    for msg in iter(q.get, None):
        print 'howdy,',msg

inq = Queue.Queue()
for word in 'whiskey syrup bitters'.split():
    inq.put(word)
inq.put( None )        # tell worker to exit

thread = threading.Thread(target=howdy, args=[inq])
thread.start()
thread.join()
```

## output

```
howdy, whiskey
howdy, syrup
howdy, bitters
```